# Not getting indexed by Google Scholar

Tags: google-scholar

Our journal is using the OJS system and has been online for more than 2 years. However, in the recent 6 months, GS stop to index any of our articles.
What we have tried :

1. Check the response of any of our article pages to make sure it is responded to 200
2. Change the domain
3. Evaluate the metadata to follow the gs guidelines.
4. As an information, our journal is included on the Google search engine

We also discuss it on the OJS forum and no one knows the answer since there is no member of the forum from the official GS staff.

Is there any person who can give us suggestions?
Is there any blacklist mechanism on GS that prevents us from getting indexed to GS?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Closer voters: In my opinion, Academia.SE exists to answer questions like these.